# CRM online client returns "An error occurred when verifying security for the message." - InvalidSecurity

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to create a client in Visual Studio 2010 to access online CRM web service.
I've added a service reference to:

```
https://<myAccountId>.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl
```

Here's the code:

```
string endPoint = "https://<myAccountId>.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl";
string UserName = "<myuser>@<mydomain>.onmicrosoft.com";
string Password = "<password>";

OrganizationServiceClient orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceClient();
orgProxy.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(endPoint);
orgProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
orgProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;

ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
cols.Columns = new[] { "fullname" };

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
query.EntityName = "contact";
query.ColumnSet = cols;

orgProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

I get this exception:

```
var exception ='<s:Fault>
        <s:Code>
            <s:Value>
                s:Sender
            </s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
                <s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    a:InvalidSecurity
                </s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
        </s:Code>
        <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">
                An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
            </s:Text>
        </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>';
```

Using CRM SDK is not an option for me, because it requires 4.0 .Net framework, and my code is all in 3.5. Thanks!

Comment: any reason why you can't upgrade your project to .NET 4.0?

Comment: The project is for Sharepoint 2010 that only supports .net 3.5. This is a part of that project and there's only a way to implement this using web services.